# gnuplot - How to rescale xaxis but using the same dataset

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following CSV data:

```
-140,0
-139,0
-138,0
...
-4,240
-3,609
-2,1426
-1,7352
+0,624209
+1,7269
+2,1376
+3,553
...
+138,0
+139,0
+140,0
```

And the following gnuplot command:

```
set terminal x11
set xrange [-10:10]
set auto y
set datafile separator ","
set xtics 1
plot 'histogram1min.csv'  using 1:2 title columnheader with boxes
pause mouse
```

This creates an histogram with x axis with values from `-10` to `+10` in steps of `1`.

I would like to change xaxis so `-10` is presented `-0.0010`, `-9` is presented as `-0.0009` etc. -i.e. instead of using `-10 to +10` we scale xaxis dividing by `1000` but using the same dataset-.

So, just to further clarify, data point `-0.001` will have value `7352`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using column 1, just do the division there. You will have to get rid of the set xrange and set xtics lines or adjust those values.

```
plot 'histogram1min.csv'  using ($1/1000):2 title columnheader with boxes
```